# try to make some Arithmetic Operations to enhance images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make some image enhancement using opencv here's my code:

```
def enhancement(img):
   matrix=np.ones((224,224),dtype='uint8')*50
   img1=cv2.add(img,matrix)
   img2=cv2.subtract(img,matrix)
   return img1,img2
```

so whenever i try to enhance my image like this

```
img=cv2.imread(imgpath)
img=cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
img1,img2=enhancement(img)
```

it gives me this error

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:650: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'
```

So can anyone help me

Comment: Your arrays (images) are not of the same size. Be sure both images have the same height, width and number of channels.

Comment: You need to ensure the number of channels of the matrix is the same as the input image

Comment: It is the number of channels. Your matrix has one channel and the images have 3 channels. Make your matrix 3 equal channels.

Comment: `matrix=  np.ones( img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)*50`. Now the matrix will be created in the same shape as the image